# Google Analytics API - Query specific URL stats

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We're building an inhouse application, and I've been tasked with researching the Google Analytics API to see what limitations there are.

Currently, it would serve us perfectly but the one task it doesn't seem to allow would be to query specific URLs.

For example, currently in GA you can go to Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages, and run a search for a specific URL.

We would like to use this functionality in our inhouse app; primarily for sales representatives who are sitting in front of a client can pull up specific analytical stats for a URL such as pageviews, time on page etc.

Does anyone have any experience with the Google Analytics API? And for those that do, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The google analytics API uses three concepts: *dimensions, metrics and filters.*

The dimension that is of interest to you is: [ga:pagePath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath), which falls under the *Page Tracking* family. This in turn tells you [which metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking) you can use with this dimension.

Let's use [ga:pageViews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pageviews) as the metric. All that is left now is to append a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) on the dimension:

```
&filters=ga:pagePath==2017 (raw string)
&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%3D2017 (encoded string)
```

For example,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=XXX&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%3D2017
```

Would effectively return the number of page views filtered against the selected page path dimension.

The [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is an effective tool to test out your requests manually. At this point, you can add any other dimension of interest, which will be filtered by the `ga:pagePath`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the Google Analytics Core Reporting API by specifying the filter query parameter.

The documentation has many examples of how to use filters and what the syntax looks like:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: Thanks Philip. I understand that much but it's creating a writeable field where external people can change the page path to inspect a pages specific stats. 

Eg, I have: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:123456789&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews&filters=ga:pagePath==/directory/page&start-date=2014-11-01&end-date=2014-11-17&max-results=50  -- I'm wanting to have the ga:pagePath parameters be dynamic based on what a user would input to a search field. I hope that makes sense

Comment: It sounds like your question is, "how do I get the value of an input field programmatically?" If that's the case, you might want to re-ask your question with the tags `html` and `javascript`, as it sounds like you already understand the Google Analytics aspect.